# else if statement for check in check out sheet vba not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet in which lies a data entry form and a check in check out list. I have a macro set up to search for the entry, and if it doesnt exist, make a new entry with a checkout time, if it does exist, it checks it back in with a time. My issue lies when I try to check out an entry that already exists. The code just updates the check in time. Ive added an elseif statement into the code but it doesnt seem to do anything. If anyone could help me figure out why itd be much appreciated.

```
Sub inout()
Dim barcode As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim rownumber As Long
 
barcode = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)

    Set rng = Sheet1.Columns("a:a").Find(What:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng = True Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = True Then
        rownumber = rng.Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownumber, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Clear
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = ""
        Cells(2, 2).Select
    ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Columns("a:a").Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = barcode
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    ElseIf rng = True Then
        rownumber = rng.Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownumber, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = ""
        rng.Offset(, 1).Clear
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "TOOL CRIB"
        Cells(2, 2).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng` will not be `True`.  Try `If Not Rng is Nothing`

Comment: perfect! that worked though it revealed a few other bugs unfortunately

Comment: You are going to run into problems using `ActiveCell, Select and Activate`.  Better to define your locations.

Comment: noted, ill try that